# Permission facebook sdk Android

Tags: android, facebook

Working on `Facebook`. Unable to get `publish_actions` permission. Using this code:

```
session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new
Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSION));
```

any solution...

Comment: When it comes to facebook and android, there's an open source library that can simplify everything to you - https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Comment: I am working on one of these sample HelloFacebook
I just changed the package name & class name  and give it a run.
It work fine for the device on which fb app is install and in other can't get publish_actions permission

Comment: I followed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share example to post to a users wall. It works fine if I login to facebook using apps developer email. With non-developers, I don't get the permissions... Did you find any answer for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
```

in `onActivityResult` do this

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null) {

        // Check for publish permissions
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermsnRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermsnRequest );
            return;
        }
    }
```

Also implement this in your class.

```
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> a,
        Collection<String> b) {
    for (String string : a) {
        if (!b.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

By doing this you will be able to get all the public permissions. you have to open the session after getting read permissions and then only request for publish permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook sdk only returns read-permission, but not the write permissions. You can user the "/me" endpoint to get all the permissions.

```
    final Bundle permBundle = new Bundle();
    permBundle.putCharSequence("permission", "publish_actions");
    GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/permissions", permBundle, HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "response2: " + graphResponse.getJSONObject());
                    try {
                        JSONArray permList = (JSONArray) graphResponse.getJSONObject().get("data");
                        if(permList.length() == 0){
                            // no data for perms, hence asking permission
                            askForFBPublishPerm();
                        }else{
                            JSONObject permData = (JSONObject) permList.get(0);
                            String permVal = (String) permData.get("status");
                            if(permVal.equals("granted")){
                                postToFB();
                            }else{
                                askForFBPublishPerm();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "exception while parsing fb check perm data" + e.toString());
                    }

                }
            }
    );
    request.executeAsync();
```