# Facebook SDK 3.8: publish_actions permission for non-developers

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm following the facebook android sharing tutorial by facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share).

The app flow is as follows:

1. Login using facebook
2. User can share a post by clicking on share button.

The above flow works when I login using facebook developer email.

When I use non-developer email, I am able to **login successfully**, but when user clicks **share** button, in the pop up, it says you already authorized the *** app. But when I print the list of permissions, the session doesn't have publish_actions permission.

I have read in some online posts that to obtain publish_actions permission from the users I have to get the app reviewed and approved from facebook. Is that correct?

I have seen similar questions on publish_actions on Stack Overflow, but they don't have any answers yet.

1. [Facebook SDK 3.8 : permission publish_actions not returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157419/facebook-sdk-3-8-permission-publish-actions-ot-returned)
2. [Permission facebook sdk Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645800/permission-facebook-sdk-android)
3. [Facebook publish_actions no longer working in desktop app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700782/facebook-publish-actions-no-longer-working-in-desktop-app)

Can anyone guide me how to publish_posts from my app to users facebook wall using facebook sdk?

Comment: To ask people that doesn't have a role on the app you need to get the permission reviewed first. Go to the Developer App and click Status & Review and submit it for review